# Route to get all requests to the root folder (no trailing slash allowed)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes

I want to catch all URL's in the root folder of the url `www.example.com`

The url cannot end in a trailing slash, and can't contain any slashes at all.

so these should pass:

```
www.example.com/abc
www.example.com/abc123-asdf
www.example.com/abc123/  ** FAIL!
```

also, the sub-folders, like:

```
www.example.com/asdfsd/asdf  ** FAIL!
```

Answer (score 0):

What web server are you using?  If you're using Apache, what you want is URL Rewriting (mod_rewrite)

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html

It has full regular expression support. and can automatically change all offending requests to the default url for you.

Comment: For IIS, you can use ISAPI Rewrite from Helicon, what is equivalent to mod_rewrite for Apache: http://www.isapirewrite.com/